# UIWebView didFinished is not called and shows blank page

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an `UIWebView`, I open a website but sometimes the delegate methods don't get called and the UIWebView shows a blank white page.
But when I use Safari to show the HTML Code in the `UIWebView` everything is loaded but not displayed.
Did anyone encounter a similar behavior?

I do nothing special

```
NSURL *url = ...
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.cordovaController.webView loadRequest:request];

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    NSLog(@"LOADING WEBSITE DONE");
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"LOADING WEBSITE DONE WITH ERROR %@", [error description]);
}
```

Comment: that url works in browser?

Comment: are you creating the url dynamically by adding some header params ?

Comment: everytime in browser in 1 of 50 tries not in UIWebView but mostly it works
@SharonNathaniel I add some POST parameters to the request

Comment: What have you got in your delegate method -[UIWebViewDelegate webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:]? Only times I've seen a webview fail to load something without actually calling the finished or failed delegate methods is when the webview hasn't even started the request ...

Comment: Generally this happens if your url is malformed, and the request cannot be started. Any errors generated in the all output console ?

Comment: no errors are shown only some warnings about pictures on the page but they are everytime there...
the url is the same all times, so it can`t be the url itself
@DavidDoyle I will check

Comment: shouldStartLoadWithRequest get called and returns true in this case

Comment: Does the page load correctly in Safari all the time? If not, does Safari log anything to the console?

Comment: thats my problem no errors are there and after 3 or 4 minutes the page appears suddenly... and all delegates get called.
but the page is completly loaded long before that happened

Comment: Aaaah ... so it IS loading, its just taking a very long time. That was going to be the next hypothesis. How long does Safari take to load that page? Could be there's some errant content on there that takes a long time but isn't immediately apparent that its not there.

Comment: Safari takes 1-2 seconds to load the page, UIWebView normally too.
Its loaded, I can see anything with the Safari debugger in the UIWebView the problem is sometimes it doen`t show the content when its loaded.
As I said it happened very rarely, I`m the only traffic on this specific site currently

Answer (score 0):

use **UIWebView** delegate method to open url

```
#pragma mark UIWebView Delegates -

    -(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
    {
        if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
            return NO;  //only open in safari not in UIWebView
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

I hope it will works for u

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at:

[UIWebview slow loading secured page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818509/uiwebview-slow-loading-secured-page)

Looks like the webview might be struggling to manage some of the authentication challenge used to connect to that page.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remember to connect (ctrl drag) the UIWebView object to the filesOwner button on the ViewController (the orange coloured button at the bottom) and select 'delegate'. You should find your code will get called now.

[image: ctrl drag from UIWebView to files owner and select "delegate"]

I hope this helps. If it does, please mark this as correct +1 etc. Cheers Jim.