# Hybrid iOS app with HTML 5 , how to supply credentials for the remote server

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, html

Created a HTML page and javascript to request a web service and alert the response on a button click. However when I open it from safari in simulator the application is asking for credentials and on supplying credentials I gets the reponse and alerts as designed.

However the same page when requested from uiwebview,call back function is  not getting fired, and it is not asking for any credentials. Any possible solutions to supply credentials to a hybrid ios app.

Comment: Is the web service prompting for HTTP Basic Auth credentials?

Comment: Yes, it is. Found a similar thread here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/02/iphone-uiwebview-http-basic-authentication/