# UIWebview Popup

Tags: ios, uiwebview, popup

i am opening a remote Website in UIWebview that shows a popup in Safari Mobile for entering user credentials. In UIWebView the popup doesn't appear.

Can anybody tell me if there is a way to enable popups?

Comment: Is it a public page? If so, please post so I can poke around at it. Thanks. -Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a problem similar to one I had - `UIWebView` does not prompt for basic authentication.  The way around it is to create a separate `NSURLConnection` with a delegate that handles authentication challenges.  After receiving a response, you can then load the original request in the `UIWebView`.

[How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview) provides some code you can start with for that.