# iOS: Authentication using XMLHttpRequest - Handling 401 response

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, xmlhttprequest, basic-authentication

I'm writing an iOS application using PhoneGap (aka Cordova), I have a simple html login page that logs the user in using an XMLHttpRequest with basic authentication over SSL.  Everything works splendidly when you enter your username and password correctly.  However, if you enter the wrong username/password none of my callbacks are ever called.

If you run the same code on Chrome for example, with the wrong username/password, chrome behaves in a similar manner, except it pops up an authentication challenge dialog.  Hitting cancel on chrome's dialog returns control to my javascript code.  Unfortunately, on iOS, the UIWebView wont even popup an auth dialog, it just hangs.  I need a way to tell the user that they entered the wrong username or password so they can retry.

The closest thing to an answer I could find was this http://www.freelock.com/2008/06/technical-note-http-auth-with-ajax but changing the response status from the server doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Here's basically what my request code looks like, but when a bad username or password is sent it never reaches my onload callback (in fact the onreadystatechange callback only gets called once and thats for readyState 1, aka OPEN).

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = function(ev) {
    if (req.status == 401) {
        alert("Invalid Username/Password");
        document.getElementById('password').focus();
    } else if (req.status == 200) {
        window.location.href = some_secure_site;
    } else {
        // edit //
        alert("Some other status");
    }
}
req.onerror = function (ev) { alert('Error'); };
req.ontimeout = function(ev) { alert('Timeout'); };
req.open('GET', uri, true, userValue, passValue);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.send();
```

Comment: Seems to be related to that issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415 please vote to get it fixed soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things became apparent to me while trying to do this on iOS.  One is that iOS has a bug relating to basic auth, so if your password has certain special characters in it you'll never get a response back from your server because your server will never get an authentication challenge.  That is, if you're using the username and password field in the "open" method.

My guess is they are doing something stupid like sending it via **http://username:password@myorigin.com/etc** when they should be using http headers and base64 encoding the creds like so

```
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64(username) + ':' + base64(password));
```

The other thing I learned is that Basic Auth isnt very secure and is prone to a million and one problems.  One of which that will annoy you is that the client will cache the username and password, which will override any new values you send via "req.open(...)".  Good luck getting around that using javascript alone, you'll have to do some magic in ObjC to clear the cache.

If you have control over your server, I would suggest using token authentication.  Connect over SSL and then send a POST with JSON data containing the username and password.  The server could then send back JSON data with an authentication token (essentially a bunch of random characters long enough that it can't ever be guessed, a UUID works well. this is generated by the server and can only be known to the client and the server).  Then store the token and the username in the keychain so the user doesnt need to enter their creds everytime they start your app.

My server will always send back a 200 response but the JSON data will contain the information needed to either retry or to store the auth token.  In general... basic auth basically sucks.

```
try {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = function(ev) {
        var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (response.success === true) {
            // The server will respond with a token that will allow us to login
            storeCredentials(userValue, response.token);
            // redirect with token
        else if (req.status == 401) {
            alert("Invalid Username/Password");
            document.getElementById('password').focus();
        } else {
            alert("Some other status");
        }
    }
    req.ontimeout = setTimeout(function(ev) { navigator.notification.alert('Timeout trying to contact the server'); }, 10000);
    req.onerror = function(ev) { clearTimeout(this.ontimeout); navigator.notification.alert('Error connecting to the server during authentication.'); };

    var uri = myWebOrigin + '/authenticate';
    req.open('POST', uri, true);
    req.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    json_data = {username : Base64.encode(userValue), password : Base64.encode(passValue)};
    req.send(JSON.stringify(json_data));
} catch(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Uh oh, an error occurred trying to login! ' + error);
    return;
}
```

Comment: If the username or password contains special characters then you could try calling encodeURIComponent(username). I had a problem with iOS + PhoneGap where correct usernames or passwords that contained these characters would fail and encoding them fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issues with none of the callbacks being called when using iOS + PhoneGap + **jQuery**. If I pass incorrect credentials and use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    timeout: 5000, // Some timeout value that makes sense
    ...
});
```

then the error callback is called with `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"timeout"}`. In that case you would have to guess that the real error is the HTTP 401.

Alternatively you can use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    async: false, // :-(
    ...
});
```

and your error callback will get something like `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html>...</html>","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}` back.

Answer (score 1):

To solved this problem remove the header `WWW-Authenticate` from server response.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an other HTTP status code beside the `401` and `200` codes received! Make sure there is really no other status code received:

```
if (req.status == 401) {
    alert("Invalid Username/Password");
    document.getElementById('password').focus();
} else if (req.status == 200) {
    window.location.href = some_secure_site;
} else {
    alert('Unfetched status code '+req.status+' captured!');
}
```

Comment: I have a similar else statement in my code and unfortunately it doesnt get called, my onload callback is never called.  Again, same behavior in chrome but chrome displays an auth dialog.  canceling the auth dialog will cause my onload callback to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue - none of the callbacks on the request are being called if invalid credentials are passed in.

My guess is that internally the UIWebView is being told to prompt for credentials, but that prompt is being suppressed, leading to this bug.  This is based on all the other browsers I've tried (Safari, Chrome, Firefox) not calling the callbacks in this case until after the prompt is dismissed.

Another solution (the one I'm using) would be to not use Javascript to do the authentication, and instead do it on the iOS side - you can use the code on [How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview) as a rough template for doing this.