# Google recaptcha not working as expected in iphone

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, recaptcha

I tried to search on the internet for this. I got a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483703/recaptcha-not-working-properly-on-iphone) but could not get a convincing answer.

I have a web page built in asp.net. I have google recaptcha on this page and is working fine on all desktop browsers and android mobile phones.

The problem is with iphones. The recaptcha does not show the image grid for the user to verify them. When the user touches the checkbox is simply gives a "tick" and lets the user through.

The model of iphone I have checked in is iphone 5C (safari) and iphone 6S (chrome 50) but I think the problem should be with all the models.

Please note it is working fine on simulators like chrome simulators.

The web page is as below:

http://www.infochoice.com.au/infochoice/contact-us.aspx

This is a live webpage so request you to please be careful and gentle in adding comments in it.

I have not added any code here in this question as I think it is more iphone device specific issue and has nothing to do with code.

Will update the question if requested.

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

reCAPTCHA actively considers a user’s entire engagement with the CAPTCHA—before, during, and after—to determine whether that user is a human.

In cases when the reCAPTCHA risk analysis engine can't confidently predict whether a user is a human or an abusive agent, it will prompt a CAPTCHA to elicit more cues, increasing the number of security checkpoints to confirm the user is valid.

Therefore some users may just be shown a simple checkbox while others may face image grid verifications.

See this blog post for more details
https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html