# UIWebView Authentication Example

Tags: ios, authentication, uiwebview, xcode4.3

I am new to IOS application. I am creating one application with UIWebView in IOS. I have followed the tutorials

[UIWebView Authentication 1/4](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CGIQtwIwBQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zCzY0StVEc&ei=G4ASUP_SFcLtrAeT5oHICg&usg=AFQjCNG2_Gfiv6Pgp52Tv2Hkz14QbnxQWg&sig2=WPi2ep9vSPH-n0MUUb7Z8g)

[UIWebView Authentication 2/4](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFwQtwIwBA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmggqIp4c28&ei=G4ASUP_SFcLtrAeT5oHICg&usg=AFQjCNEsVEvxXPJOIml7enmBzFrLi_aUYQ&sig2=Mz-AhBWpwmu9Uxk3jxwTfg)

[UIWebView Authentication 3/4](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CFYQtwIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cduDCj31Xgs&ei=G4ASUP_SFcLtrAeT5oHICg&usg=AFQjCNEAzDSKNCaSAZVQrMPyehi6yDY9Sg&sig2=0wHbXt1QtiGIQcufb2o8SQ)

[UIWebView Authentication 4/4](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CGgQtwIwBg&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=28NavUXU2go&ei=G4ASUP_SFcLtrAeT5oHICg&usg=AFQjCNGYE15AZvZkM9VSfappqirLP3Vj_A&sig2=KDjwvO1AlrL4C2KIgsXKBw)

and referred many sites. But not getting clear idea.

Could you please give me the solution for the following question

> 1. What is Authentication in UIWebView?
> 2. Why I have to use Authentication?
> 3. Please give me a proper simple example with Authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit a webpage in a regular browser (Safari, Firefox), and the webpage requires basic authentication, you'll get prompted for a username and password.  For general web browsing, you don't need to worry about it unless you're trying to load a secure site.

[How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview) provides a good example of loading a UIWebView with a page that requires basic authentication.

If you are looking for information on other types of authentication, you will have to be more specific.