# Handling authentication in a UIWebView iOS.How does this work?

Tags: ios, authentication, cookies, ios-simulator

I had a requirement where i had to handle authentication of a  site and load it  in a UIWebview .After searching the net 
for while I created a new NSURLConnection and handled the authentication challenge(as in the link [How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview) ) using that

Everything works fine but i don't understand the following piece of code.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSString *newUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", response.URL];

        // cancel the connection. we got what we want from the response,
        // no need to download the response data.
        [connection cancel];


        //Start loading the new request in webView
        NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];
        NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

}
```

Here webview is simply loading the request again without resending any auth info in  the cookies.Then i understood that **iOS
handles cookie management automatically**.But when i tried to access the cookies and print it after the authentication,it gave nothing.I used the following piece 
of code to retrieve all the cookies.

```
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]
```

How does this work then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was some issue with the simulator at that time.I was able to print the cookies while running the app on the device.