# UIWebview Login into authenticated site, then need to login again

Tags: ios, authentication, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am having trouble implement this.

Theres a UIwebview that holds a site which required to login. I first created a login modal page for the user to login, and this part is DONE.

I used the code from here: [How to display the Authentication Challenge in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview)

Now, once the user logged in, he/she is sitting inside the secured mobile site. But there are some links in the mobile site which requires to login again.

Right now I am doing it in a hacky way, in the method of:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

I check and see if the `request.url` is equal to `"https://www.#$%^&.com"`, if yes, then i will `set _authed = NO`, and basically do the login process again.

It works fine, but if there are 100+ of links that required to logins again, I will have to add 100+ of url to my if-statement, in order to catch it.

I am hoping someone can help me figure out a better way to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write javascript function in your web page and call login method from there. you just need to pass username and password from modal page. Execute javascript in `webViewDidFinishLoad` like below

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"DoLogin('%@','%@','%@');",username,password,redirectURL];
```

Comment: Hi, what is that "redirectURL"?

Comment: if you want to redirect any other page except home page like in my example, after login i am redirecting to settings page. its not just parameter of my function

Comment: hmmm, i dont think it works, cuz webviewdidFinishLoad will get never called when I click a link that requires NTLM authentication. webview did start, but never finished