# UIWebView does not initially load certain URLs

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Having such a bizarre issue with the UIWebView and I haven't been able to find a solution online. I have an iPad app that has a web view in it. Upon first install and run of the app, I try to load [an education website](http://my.tac.edu.au). The web view just hangs and times out. I kill the app, I run it again, and it loads just fine. [This one works fine](http://www.tac.edu.au) which is also part of the education website. I'm pulling my hair out!

Some code:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.tac.edu.au"];
   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: websiteUrl];
   [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

Works fine with www.tac.edu.au. I don't know what it is about that URL that makes it hang **only** when the app is first installed. You stop it, run it again (without uninstalling) and it comes up just fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your site prompts credential to move to your page. You are facing auth challenge here. Read this question for more http://stackoverflow.com/q/1769888/468724

Comment: THAT makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: I hope you have solved your problem and I don't like your 69 reps so increased to 74.

Comment: you definitely solved it. Wish I could give you more rep for it. Aww I liked my 69 reps ):  Lol thanks though.

Comment: :D :D .. Anyways you can check my other [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/468724/inder-kumar-rathore?tab=answers)

Answer (score 0):

:)

instead of view did appear  , write the code in view will appear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   NSURL *websiteUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.tac.edu.au"];
   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: websiteUrl];
   [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
   self.webview.delegate = self;
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
  //Start Activity Indicator
}
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

   //End activity indicator
}
```

Comment: I wish this was that easy! Thanks for the help though. Unfortunately it did not work. It was the auth challenge.