# Is avaiable Authentication required pop up message in UIWebView?

Tags: uiwebview, nsurlconnection, uiwebviewdelegate

Here i use XCode 5. I did enter a URL in iphone safari browser. it will be show authentication required pop up. Show like authentication required pop up image beolw.

[image]

Is possible show authentication required pop up in UIWebview?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Yes. i tried it. But dnt get it. Please help me

Comment: @Okuma.Scott Is possible show authentication required pop up in UIWebview?

Comment: @Okuma.Scott But in iphone safari will show

Comment: please post the relevant portions of your code and tell us what error message you get, if any.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
 [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:http://username:password@subdomain.companyname.com/]];
```

Also have a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview)