# How to detect all authentication challenges originated from uiwebview page

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, authentication, uiwebview

I have UIWebView page on which there is a button of **Login** which does login using basic authentication and HTTP POST method call to a server api **https://www.abc.com/login**. I am not able to detect the the authentication challenge for it through NSURLConnection as specified here
[Display Authentication Challenge iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769888/how-to-display-the-authentication-challenge-in-uiwebview). Because of the reason that authentication request is not the request that is originally loaded in the webview.

The hack to this can be when authentication request is made load a custom url in webview detect that in iOS code and start a new request in iOS with the URL to  **https://www.abc.com/login** which works fine. But is there any other way to do it?